# Proper type to use in useRef for Material-UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-ref

Using react hooks with Material-UI and TypeScript I'm unable to find a proper type `T` for the Material-UI *TextField* component. Therefore I am resorting to using `HTMLInputElement` as the *RefObject* `T` parameter because it also has a `focus` method.

```
  const focus = (inputRef: RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (inputRef.current !== null) {
      inputRef.current.focus()
    }
  }
```

What replacement of `HTMLInputElement` will work properly for representing the `TextField` API in the *RefObject* in this case? I was hoping Material-UI would export something like *"TextFieldRef"* at least, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Just to be clear I'm not using an `HTMLInputElement` anywhere in my code, using this is just a hack to get TypeScript to work properly with this, cause both `TextField` from Material-UI and `HTMLInputElement` have a `focus` method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your IDE probably shows you the type when you hover over `ref`

Comment: `HTMLInputElement` is the appropriate type to use.

Comment: @RyanCogswell But this is not an `HTMLInputElement`, it's a Material-UI `TextField` component.

Comment: @GabrielRatener Yes, it is an `HTMLInputElement`. You are confusing the React component type (MUI's `TextField`) responsible for labelling and styling the input with the html form element type that it renders which in the end is still `<input type="text">`. You can inspect a MUI TextField using the browser developer tools to look at the rendered html.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it really depends on what are you trying to achieve.
are you trying to focus the input of the text field or the root element?

from MUI docs:

> The `ref` is forwarded to the root element.

to get a ref to the `<input />` element you should use the `inputRef` prop. [You can read about it here.](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/)
In this case, you shall indeed use the `HTMLInputElement` since it is an input behind the scenes.

---

Let's dive into mui code base:

[TextField](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/174076bc3c/packages/mui-material/src/TextField/TextField.js) code base indeed reveals an `InputComponent` which receive the `inputRef` prop.

In case you do want to get a ref to to root element, we can see that `TextFieldRoot` component is the root element which receive the ref.
line 179:

```js
    <TextFieldRoot
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
      disabled={disabled}
      error={error}
      fullWidth={fullWidth}
      ref={ref}
      required={required}
      color={color}
      variant={variant}
      ownerState={ownerState}
      {...other}
    >
```

so lets explore where does it get from.
we can see it is a styled `FormControl` component. from line 33:

```js
const TextFieldRoot = styled(FormControl, {
  name: 'MuiTextField',
  slot: 'Root',
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => styles.root,
})({});
```

From [FormControl code](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/174076bc3c571e52868e535391b85777a4d2c78e/packages/mui-material/src/FormControl/FormControl.js) we can understand that `FormControlRoot` root receive the ref as prop, line 215:

```js
  return (
    <FormControlContext.Provider value={childContext}>
      <FormControlRoot
        as={component}
        ownerState={ownerState}
        className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
        ref={ref}
        {...other}
      >
        {children}
      </FormControlRoot>
    </FormControlContext.Provider>
  );
});
```

and finally, from line 22 we can understand it is just a styled div..

```
const FormControlRoot = styled('div', { 
...
```

So now, based on MUI base code, you can choose between `HTMLInputElement` and `HTMLDivElement` by your needs.